# Search a text file and print related lines in Python?

Tags: python, file, search

How do I search a text file for a key-phrase or keyword and then print the line that key-phrase or keyword is in?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
searchfile = open("file.txt", "r")
for line in searchfile:
    if "searchphrase" in line: print line
searchfile.close()
```

To print out multiple lines (in a simple way)

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
searchlines = f.readlines()
f.close()
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "searchphrase" in line: 
        for l in searchlines[i:i+3]: print l,
        print
```

The comma in `print l,` prevents extra spaces from appearing in the output; the trailing print statement demarcates results from different lines.

Or better yet (stealing back from Mark Ransom):

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    searchlines = f.readlines()
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "searchphrase" in line: 
        for l in searchlines[i:i+3]: print l,
        print
```

Comment: close the file after processing.

Comment: How would I print that line and three other lines below it?

Comment: senderle, before I accept your answer can you, or someone else, explain how I would print three lines below the searched line as well?

Comment: file.readlines() is not very efficient for large files. use file.read() instead

Comment: @ekta, the OP asked for line numbers, so the data will have to be broken into lines somehow. What in your opinion would do so more efficiently than `readlines`?

Comment: infile = =open('filename', 'rb')

Comment: @senderle I was working over something like this and also found this useful while working over my task, please can you briefly explain how you arrived at this and why ? bief code explanation please

Answer (score 23):

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if 'searchphrase' in line:
            print line
```

With apologies to [senderle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785244/how-would-i-search-a-text-file-in-python/4785306#4785306) who I blatantly copied.

Comment: +1. I was annoyed -- but then I took a moment to understand the with statement. This is great!

Comment: @senderle, thanks for that. I considered just editing your answer, but I thought that would be even more annoying - and the `with` statement is a rather recent addition to Python, making your answer the most appropriate for some people. You got my +1 long ago!

Comment: yes, a recent and to me, cryptic, addition, until just now; I have to admit that I had struggled to grok the with statement a few weeks ago and had come up blank -- but this simple example explains it perfectly.

Comment: Nice. For others just stumbling on this, this method automatically closes the file afterwards. There's a good explanation at effbot.org: [Understanding Python's "with" statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Note the potential for an out-of-range index with "i+3".  You could do something like:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    searchlines = f.readlines()
j=len(searchlines)-1
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "searchphrase" in line: 
        k=min(i+3,j)
        for l in searchlines[i:k]: print l,
        print
```

Edit:  maybe not necessary.  I just tested some examples.  x[y] will give errors if y is out of range, but x[y:z] doesn't seem to give errors for out of range values of y and z.

Comment: Slicing doesn't produce out of range errors. When you take a slice, you say "give me a list of the items in this range." If there are no items in the given range, then an empty list delivers what was asked for. On the other hand, indexing says "give me the exact item at index `i`." If there is no item at `i`, then returning something -- even `None` -- would be a lie, so it's better to raise an exception.