# Searching a text file for a user given string

Tags: file, text, python-3.x, full-text-search

I have programmed a working game which gives the user a random string of 7 letters, and the user must use only these letters to make combinations of words and non-words, each letter used only once. This has already been nearly perfected, with an occasional bug.

My main issue is that when trying to determine the point value for the strings, I take three factors: length, value of each letter (based on Scrabble values) and if it is a real word or not. I downloaded the dictionary found [here](http://www.zyzzyva.net/wordlists.shtml).
This file was saved as a `.txt` file on my Ubuntu computer, and I used several different ways to search the file for the inputs (because the file has all of the words in capital letters, I set the variable 'capital' to the `input.upper().` Points are added up by taking `(length+lettervalues) * realword`. If `realword == 2`, score is doubled

```
dictionary = open('wordlist.txt', 'r')
for line in dictionary:
    if capitals in line:
        realword = 2
    else:
        realword = 1
dictionary.close()
```

I have also tried the solutions at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785244/how-would-i-search-a-text-file-in-python).
This did not give me any working solutions either. With every attempt, it does not crash of have any errors- it simply goes to the else statement each and every time. I would be extremely appreciative if this problem is resolved. I have been banging my head on my keyboard for two days.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you supply the rest of the code?  Particularly where you get the input, transform it, and assign to the variable `capitals`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to the site. Is there an easy way to upload the source code, because I feel like it would not be convenient to write it all in a comment

Comment: Edit your main post to include it.  Or at least the relevant portions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't require the else statement. Initialize realword to 1 and change to 2 only if its found in the dictionary and break. Also, most of the dictionaries have word as well as meaning on the same line, so try to split it up i.e.choose the first word before spacebar.

```
capitals= input('enter word').upper()

realword = 1
dictionary = open('wordlist.txt', 'r')
for line in dictionary:
    if capitals == line.split()[0]:
        realword = 2
        break

print (realword)
dictionary.close()
```

Comment: With this also, I am getting the error that line is a tuple, and therefore cannot be stripped

Comment: This code worked better, but only when [0] was excluded. When I put that in, I got an index error saying that the string was out of range. Without [0], almost every word counted because every string can be found in the document(ex. ytho is in Python)

Comment: I don't know what you did. But it must work. Its working correctly in my computer. Try to copy and paste the code and see. [0] is required to get the first string.

Comment: I have updated the comment with complete code. Please check it again. Just try the code and nothing else and see.

Comment: GOT IT! With your code, if capitals was not in it, it gave an IndexError. Knowing this ahead of time, I used the try command between the "for line in ..." statement and the "if capitals..." prompt. Then, I excepted the IndexError, and simply set realworld to 1. This helped me so much!