# Using python to search a text file for the occurence of specific characters

Tags: python, regex, file, search

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785244/how-would-i-search-a-text-file-in-python?s=c09c0e5a-9367-4b99-b0be-672d5b132053), except that I want to search for the occurrence of multiple `chars`, for example `g`, `d` and `e`, and then print the line in which ALL the specified characters exist.

I have tried the following but it didn't work:

```
searchfile = open("myFile.txt", "r")
for line in searchfile:
    if ('g' and 'd') in line: print line,
searchfile.close()
```

I was getting lines which had EITHER 'g' or 'd' or both in them, all I want is just both occurences, not at least one of them, as is the result of running the above code.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? This isn't hard to implement and doesn't require regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
if ('g' and 'd') in line:
```

is the same as

```
if 'd' in line:
```

because

```
>>> 'g' and 'd'
'd'
```

You want

```
if 'g' in line and 'd' in line:
```

or, better:

```
if all(char in line for char in 'gde'):
```

(You could use set intersection too, but that's less generalizable.)

Answer (score 5):

```
if set('gd').issubset(line)
```

This has the advantage of not going through twice as each check of `c in line` iterates through the entire line

Answer (score 0):

regular expressions will certainly help you when it comes to pattern matching, but it seem s that your search is easier than this. Try the following:

```
# in_data, an array of all lines to be queried (i.e. reading a file)
in_data = [line1, line2, line3, line4]

# search each line, and return the lines which contain all your search terms
for line in in_data:
    if ('g' in line) and ('d' in line) and ('e' in line):
        print(line)
```

Something this simple should work. I am making a few assumptions here:
    1. the order of the search terms does not matter
    2. upper / lower case is not dealt with
    3. the frequency of the search terms is not considered.

Hope it helps.

Comment: oops, just read your sample code above - and ran it on a test file with the expected output, i.e. only returned lines with BOTH terms in them. And realise, my sample if really identical to yours :)

Comment: `'g' and 'd' and 'e' in line` won't work-- that's equivalent to `'e' in line`; nonempty strings like `'g'` and `'e'` are true-like.  For example, `line = 'fred'; print 'g' and 'd' and 'e' in line` prints True.