# Searching for one-word string occupying a line of a text with Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, text, full-text-search

I have (very) long document (in .txt) that has this format:

```
 Title
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 

 Whatever
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
```

I would like to collect a column of all the titles before each text. For now I have a problem identifying them and printing them out. 
I focus on the fact that there is an `\n` character before and after the 'title' of each text. I am not sure how to tell to python to select that 'title' that lies between the `\n` characters regardless of its length.

I used the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785244/search-a-text-file-and-print-related-lines-in-python)

```
text = "\n" + "" + "\n"
searchfile = open("MyTEXT.txt", "r") 
for line in searchfile:
    if str(text) in line: print line
searchfile.close()
```

There are two problems with the code above that I do not know how to solve:

1) The first `\n` is in a different line (the line above), so the code above finds nothing.

2) The 'Title' string that I would like to collect are in varying lengths, some are 4 characters, but some are more (not more than 10).

Any suggestions will be very helpful,
thank you in advance!

Comment: Are there any lines, other than the title lines, that have only 1 word?

Comment: Yes but they always have the same word so I will be doing an `word-found not in unwanted-name-list` to silence them. I am checking regular expressions now as some of the Title-words may contain numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
with open("MyTEXT.txt", "r") as myfile:
    wordlist = [line.rstrip('\n').split() for line in myfile]

titlelist = [i[0] for i in wordlist if len(i) == 1 and i[0] != "unwanted"]
```

For example, if `MyTEXT.txt` contained:

```
unwanted
12345 2124

abcd
efghi jkl mn

o
pqr 123

unwanted
stu v

wq
y z

unwanted
567 890
```

The output would be:

```
>>> titlelist
['abcd', 'o', 'wq']
```

Comment: This code finds all the different words of the text, whereas I am interested only in the paragraph titles. I tried through this regular expression `TITLE = re.findall(r"[0-9a-qA-Z\\n]", filetext)` which gave me all the characters of the text :-( I will try to study your code and ammend it

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. The script I wrote only gets the titles.

Comment: I think you might be looking at `wordlist`. The list that contains all the titles is called `titlelist`.

Comment: Yes, it does work, you edited your answer but I had used the previous code, a wholeheartedly thank you!