# How to search for a word through a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

This may be a very easy question but I'm new to python and I've searched the net however I couldn't solve the problem. I have a csv file which I need to search for a specific word in the columns of its first row. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search a text file and print related lines in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785244/search-a-text-file-and-print-related-lines-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

I used the default csv module of python to read a csv file line by line. Since you specified that we have to search only in the first row, that's why I used break-to stop execution after searching the first row of the csv. You can remove the break, to search throughout the csv. Hope this works.

```
import csv
a='abc'     #String that you want to search
with open("testing.csv") as f_obj:
    reader = csv.reader(f_obj, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:      #Iterates through the rows of your csv
        print(line)          #line here refers to a row in the csv
        if a in line:      #If the string you want to search is in the row
            print("String found in first row of csv")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
a='abc'     #String that you want to search
with open("testing.csv") as f_obj:
    reader = csv.reader(f_obj, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:      #Iterates through the rows of your csv
        print(line)          #line here refers to a row in the csv
        if a in str(line):      #If the string you want to search is in the row
            print("String found in first row of csv")
        break
```

You'll have to add "str(line)" to convert the line to string and then compare it.