# How to search for a word in a txt file, then print the line that contains that word(Python)?

Tags: python, search

Does anyone have any idea how could I make that work?
Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search a text file and print related lines in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785244/search-a-text-file-and-print-related-lines-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Very basic method:

```
with open("file.txt") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        if "text" in line:
            print line
```