# Storing and Printing data from text file in Python

Tags: python, file-handling

I have a program that takes input from user like;
Name, Age and Email.

I store this info in a list **(list1)** then convert this list to string **(mylist)** and write to a text file like this:

```
mylist = str(list1)
with open("StudentRecord.txt",'a') as f:
                f.write(merge+"\n")
```

This works fine to write to file and read/display the whole file.

My Question is: How do I search for a particular string in the text file and return data from it.
For example: User types a name and we look for that string in file and return his age.

Format of Text file is like this:

```
James, 29, jimmy@company.com
Anthony, 29, jimmy@company.com
Jason, 29, jimmy@company.com
```

User wants to find age of Jason.

Comment: Possible duplicate:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785244/search-a-text-file-and-print-related-lines-in-python

Comment: If you have many rows...I will recommend to use pandas ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Giovani stated in his comment, for large sets of data pandas would be a better option. However you can search and retrieve a users age via lists & list comprehension as follows;

```
with open('file.txt') as file:
    data = list(file)    

name = input('Enter a Name: ')

age = [i.split(',')[1].strip() for i in data if name in i][0]

print(f"Name: {name}\nAge: {age}")

Enter a Name: James
Name: James
Age: 29
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
import re
name = input("Enter the name\n")

with open("f.txt",'r') as f:
    line=f.readlines()
    for i in line:
        if re.match(name,i):
            age=re.findall(r'\d+',i)

print(f"Age of the {name} is {int(age[0])}")
```

I have used regular expression to find the age corresponds to the search string

[image]